# Fill textbox from selected value in dropdown

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a dropdown called `product1` and a textbox called `price1`. The dropdown is filled with `products` from the database. I want to show the `price` of te selected `product` in the textbox called 'price1'.

I am using the following table structure:

```
forms (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sort` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `prices` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

With the following code I am trying to fill the textbox with the selected value.

```
//filename: test.php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' onChange='getstate(this.value);' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id='". $product1 ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "<div id='price-list'>";
              echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='price1' id='price1' value='" . $row["price"]. "'>";
          echo "</div>";

     }                   
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>  

<script>
         function getprice(val) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test.php",
              data:'id='+val,
              success: function(data){
                $("#price-list").html(data);
              }
            });
          }
</script>

<?php
$product1=$_POST['price1'];
?>
```

When I select a product in dropdown, nothing is happening.

Can anyone help me to fix this code?

Thanks!

**Update 1:** Still not working

```
//filename: index.php

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' onChange='getstate(this.value);' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
<html>

<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="product_name" type="text">

</html>

<script>
function getPrice() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('.select2 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: 'id=' + selectedItem,
        success: function(response){
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#product_name').val(response);  
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

And

```
    //filename: get.php

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $productId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    $query = 'SELECT price FROM forms WHERE id=' . $productId;

    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fecth_assoc($res);

        print($result['price']);

    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: `getstate()` appears as a onchange event, what is this function?

Comment: After changing the selected product, I am trying to get the value of the selected product with `getstate()`

Comment: Sorry, it may not have been clear, please include the contents of the  `getstate()` function into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On your select you are putting the callback for **onchange**, use it to call a javascript function and in this funcion get the value and populate your text field.

```
...
<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' 
    onchange='changeValue();' style='width: 100%;'>

<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="product_name" type="text">
...

function changeValue() {

    // getting the selected text in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('.select2 option:selected').text;


    // and putting in text field
    jQuery('#product_name').val(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Now I have a new textbox that shows me the `ID` of the selected value. But how can I show the `price`?

Comment: Oh, I did it wrong. I'll edit the answer with the fix.

Comment: If this fix doesn't work, try this: `$(".select2 option:selected").html();`. Tell me if works, so I can to update my answer.

Comment: When I use the code: `('.select2 option:selected').text;` it shows the name of the product. `(".select2 option:selected").html();` shows the same. But I want to get the price `$sql = "SELECT price FROM forms WHERE id='". $product1 ."'";`

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand all your problem. If you have not the prices listed in some place, you must to do and Ajax request to get the price based on selected product.

Comment: How can I do that request? I have the prices in sql, can I use a sql query to get the prices?

Comment: Yep, you can to do by 2 ways. 1) execute a sql query when combo is changed; 2) you send all products price to a javascript array and get the value when combo is changed.

Comment: Still not working, check `Update 1` at my first post

Comment: Yep, I note that you call `getstate` on change option in combo, but you created the function `getPrice` and is not calling by it.

Comment: I changed `onChange='getstate(this.value);'` in `onChange='getPrice();'` but still no results

Comment: Man, excuse to be rude, if the **complete solution** I passed to you isn't working, the problem is you. Verify each little detail and try again, what I posted as answer always worked for me.

Comment: See you developer console log on your browser to identify the error

Comment: The only thing I get in my developer console log is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not defined | onchange @ (index):1`

Answer (score 0):

While you have all in the same script *test.php* you probably introduced the basic problem that you do not distinguish between…

- the case when you are **setting up the page** (first call) with the product list and
- the case when you are **posting the product id to get the price** (AJAX call, whenever the user chooses a different product).

The two cases can be distinguished by the presence of the variable ***$_POST['id']*** (*isset($_POST['id']*). The variable *$_POST['price1']* however is never transmitted and used.

I've puzzled it together (without having it tested). Try it out:

```
<?php
//filename: test.php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if (!isset($_POST['id'])) { // First call: setup the page -----------------------------

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "database";

    echo '<html>
<head>      
    <script>
     function getprice(val) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test.php",
          data:\'id=\'+val,
          success: function(data){
            $("#price-list").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' onChange='getprice(this.value);' style='width: 100%;'>";
    if ( ($result!==false) && ($result->num_rows > 0) ) {
        echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
        }                   
    }
    if ($result) mysqli_free_result($result);
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<div id="price-list">';
    echo '</div>';

echo '</body>
</html>
';

} else {                    // Ajax call, $_POST['id'] is set -------------------------

    $product1 = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id='". $product1 ."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ( ($result!==false) && ($result->num_rows > 0) ) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='price1' id='price1' value='" . $row["price"]. "'>";
            break;
        }                   
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    if ($result) mysqli_free_result($result);

}

$conn->close(); // Drop connection

?>
```

Comment: I get: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'POST' (T_STRING) in C:\Program Files (x86)\....................\test.php on line 23`

Comment: In the $.ajax ... type: "POST" clause?

Answer (score 0):

After read your comments I understand that what you need is to get the product price when the combo is changed, but you still don't have these prices. So you can to do an Ajax request to get the price.

```
...
<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' 
onchange='getPrice();' style='width: 100%;'>

<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="product_name" type="text">
...

function getPrice() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('.select2 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'your-php-file-to-do-query-in-database.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: 'product_id=' + selectedItem,
        success: function(response){
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#product_name').val(response);  
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
    });
}
```

In you PHP file you must to make a query in database to get product price.

```
$productId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$query = 'SELECT price FROM products WHERE id=' . $productId;
//execute the query in database and return the result

// In this example I will suppose you used the mysql_* functions
// to get the price

$res = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $result = mysql_fecth_assoc($res);

    print($result['price']);

    // and finally ends the script
    die();
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Still not working, check `Update 1` at my first post